# Undefined variable: banners in Blade Laravel 7.x

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel 7.x. I'm getting an error "Undefined variable: banners (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mytravel\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)
" Please help to find Where is the problem and how can i solve it?

Here is **BannerController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Banner;

class BannerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // $banners = Banner::all()->toArrary();
        // return view('admin.index', ['banners' =>$banners]));

        $banners = Banner::all();
        return view('admin.index', compact('banners'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.layout.bannercustomize');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'h4_title' => 'required',
            'h2_title' => 'required',
            'banner_paragraph' => 'required'
        ]);

        $banner = new Banner([
            'h4_title' => $request->get('h4_title'),
            'h2_title' => $request->get('h2_title'),
            'banner_paragraph' => $request->get('banner_paragraph'),
        ]);
        $banner->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data Added');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is **web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/contact-us', function () {
    return view('contactus');
});

Route::get('/tours', function () {
    return view('tours');
});

// Admin panel Pages Routes

Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin/index');
});

Route::get('/admin/bannercustomize', function () {
    return view('admin/layout/bannercustomize');
});
// Controller routes
Route::resource('banner', 'BannerController');
```

Here is model **Banner.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['h4_title', 'h2_title', 'banner_paragraph', 'banner_photo'];
}
```

Here is **index.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
<div class="container-scroller">
      <!-- partial:partials/_navbar.html -->
      @include('admin.layout.nav')

      <!-- partial -->
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
        <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
        @include('admin.layout.sidebar')
        <!-- partial -->
        <div class="main-panel">
          <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Page Title Header Starts-->
            <div class="row page-title-header">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                  <h4 class="page-title">Dashboard</h4>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Page Title Header Ends-->


            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                          <h4 class="card-title mb-0">Banner</h4>
                          <a href="#"><small>Show All</small></a>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est quod cupiditate esse fuga</p>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>H4 Title</th>
                                <th>H2 Title</th>
                                <th>Paragraph</th>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              @foreach($banners as $banner)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{$banner->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$banner->h4_title}}</td>
                                <td>{{$banner->h2_title}}</td>
                                <td>{{$banner->banner_paragraph}}</td>
                                <td>no image</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
          <!-- partial:partials/_footer.html -->
          @include('admin.layout.footer')
          <!-- partial -->
        </div>
        <!-- main-panel ends -->
    </div>
      <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
</div>
<!-- container-scroller -->

@endsection
```

*N.B: I'm trying to show all my table data in admin index.blade.php file*

Answer (score 2):

You have a callback in your route .. In this function its redirecting to the blade without the data,, So you are not getting the data in blade .. Its never going to the controller

Comment: Good explanation @Abir

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this

```
Route::get('/',   'BannerController@index');
```

Comment: Is this
`Route::get('/',   'BannerController@index');`
 Instead of
`Route::resource('banner', 'BannerController');`
?